# A list with their position via for loop in racket

Tags: racket

```
(define  ( addposition x )
            (cond
              [(empty? x) "empty list"]  
              [#t (for/list ([i x])
                    (list i (add1 (index-of x i))))] 
              ))
(addposition (list 'a 'b 'c ))
```

it returns me '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)), but I need the list like '(a 1 b 2 c 3)

Answer (score 1):

As a bare minimum to get what you want you can throw that nested list to a `(flatten)` call:

```
> (flatten '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)))
'(a 1 b 2 c 3)
```

But overall the idea to build mini lists with `index-of` and then flattening it is not the most performant. Nor will it be correct if your list contains duplicate values.

If we keep our own record of the next index, and using recursion instead of the otherwise handy `for/list` structure, we can build our list this way:

```
(define (add-positions xs [ind 0])
  (if (null? xs)
      xs
      (append (list (first xs) ind)
              (add-positions (rest xs) (add1 ind))
              )))


(add-positions '(a b c d))
;=> '(a 0 b 1 c 2 d 3)
```

Comment: I did with recursion previously but can't find anything how to do via  for loop, Thank you though,

Answer (score 1):

This can be expressed pretty naturally using `map` and `flatten`:

```racket
;;; Using map and flatten:
(define (list-pos xs (start 0))
  (flatten (map (lambda (x y) (list x y))
                xs
                (range start (+ start (length xs))))))
```

Here `map` creates a list of lists, each containing one value from the input list and one value from a range list starting from `start`, and `flatten` flattens the result.

This seems more natural to me than the equivalent using `for/list`, but tastes may differ:

```racket
;;; Using for/list:
(define (list-pos xs (start 0))
  (flatten (for/list ((x xs)
                      (p (range start (+ start (length xs)))))
             (list x p))))
```

There are a lot of ways that you could write this, but I would avoid using `append` in loops. This is an expensive function, and calling `append` repeatedly in a loop is just creating unnecessary overhead. You could do this:

```racket
;;; Using Racket default arguments and add1:
(define (list-pos xs (pos 0))
  (if (null? xs)
      xs
      (cons (car xs)
            (cons pos (list-pos (cdr xs) (add1 pos))))))
```

Here the first element of the list and a position counter are added onto the front of the result with every recursive call. This isn't tail recursive, so you might want to add an accumulator:

```racket
;;; Tail-recursive version using inner define:
(define (list-pos xs (start 0))
  (define (loop xs pos acc)
    (if (null? xs)
        (reverse acc)
        (loop (cdr xs)
              (add1 pos)
              (cons pos
                    (cons (car xs) acc)))))
  (loop xs start '()))
```

Because the intermediate results are collected in an accumulator, `reverse` is needed to get the final result in the right order.

You could (and I would) replace the inner `define` with a *named `let`*. Named `let` should work in Racket or Scheme; here is a Scheme version. Note that Scheme does not have default arguments, so an optional argument is used for `start`:

```scheme
;;; Tail-recursive Scheme version using named let:
(define (list-pos xs . start)
  (let loop ((xs xs)
             (pos (if (null? start) 0 (car start)))
             (acc '()))
    (if (null? xs)
        (reverse acc)
        (loop (cdr xs)
              (add1 pos)
              (cons pos
                    (cons (car xs) acc))))))
```

All of the above versions have the same behavior:

```
list-pos.rkt> (list-pos '(a b c))
'(a 0 b 1 c 2)
list-pos.rkt> (list-pos '(a b c) 1)
'(a 1 b 2 c 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using `for/fold`

```
(define (addposition l)
  (for/fold ([accum empty]) ([elem l])
    (append accum elem)))
```

I love the for loops in Racket

Note: As pointed out by ad absurdum, append is expensive here. So we can simply `reverse` first and then use `cons` to accumulate

```
(define (addposition l)
  (for/fold ([accum empty]) ([elem (reverse l)])
    (cons (first elem) (cons (second elem) accum))))
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you can start by making a list of lists.  Let's use a [list comprehension](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html):

```
> (for/list ([x '(a b c)]
             [pos (in-naturals 1)])
    (list x pos))
'((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
```

Here, we iterate in parallel over two sets of data:

1. The list `'(a b c)`
2. The stream `(in-naturals 1)`, which produces `1, 2, 3, ...`.

We combine them into lists with `list`, giving this structure:

```
'((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
```

This is called "zipping", and using list comprehensions is a convenient way to do it in Racket.

Next, we want to flatten our list, so it ends up looking like this:

```
'(a 1 b 2 c 3)
```

However, you shouldn't use `flatten` for this, as it flattens not just the outermost list, but any sub-lists as well.  Imagine if we had data like this, with a nested list in the middle:

```
> (flatten
   (for/list ([x '(a (b c d) e)]
              [pos (in-naturals 1)])
     (list x pos)))
'(a 1 b c d 2 e 3)
```

The nested list structure got clobbered!  We don't want that.  Unless we have a good reason, we should preserve the internal structure of each element in the list we're given.  We'll do this by using `append*` instead, which flattens only the outermost list:

```
> (append*
   (for/list ([x '(a (b c d) e)]
              [pos (in-naturals 1)])
     (list x pos)))
'(a 1 (b c d) 2 e 3)
```

Now that we've got it working, let's put it into a function:

```
> (define (addposition xs)
    (append*
     (for/list ([x xs]
                [pos (in-naturals 1)])
       (list x pos))))
> (addposition '(a b c))
'(a 1 b 2 c 3)
> (addposition '(a (b c d) e))              
'(a 1 (b c d) 2 e 3)
```

Looks good!

Answer (score 0):

If [`for/list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29) allowed the body to return multiple values to add to the result list, it'd be very simple to use for this. It might not, but it turns out to be easy to make a version that does:

```lisp
(require syntax/parse/define
         (for-syntax racket/base syntax/for-body))

(define-syntax-parse-rule (for/list/mv clauses body ... tail-expr)
  #:with original this-syntax
  #:with ((pre-body ...) (post-body ...)) (split-for-body this-syntax #'(body ... tail-expr))
  (for/foldr/derived original
    ([result '()])
    clauses
    pre-body ...
    (call-with-values
     (lambda () post-body ...)
     (lambda vals
       (append vals result)))))
```

Given this macro, you can now do

```lisp
> (for/list/mv ([elem (in-list '(a b c))] [pos (in-naturals 1)]) (values elem pos))
'(a 1 b 2 c 3)
```

Note the use of a *right fold* to build the list from the end to the beginning; as long as the body isn't returning a ton of different values, this makes the use of `append` much more efficient and eliminates the need for reversing lists like in some answers. On the other hand that makes it not tail recursive so it can end up using more memory.

Comment: The basic idea here is to, instead of writing a special-purpose function, create a more general high level tool that can be used to solve this problem and used beyond it in other tasks.